# Parameterization of Triangulated Surface Meshes

Tags: cgal, texture-mapping

I’d like to perform a surface parametrization of a triangle mesh (for the purpose of texture mapping).
I tried using some of [CGAL’s algorithms](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html#fig__Surface_mesh_parameterizationfigbase), e.g. ARAP, Discrete Conformal Map etc.
The problem is that the surface parameterization methods proposed by CGAL only deal with meshes which are homeomorphic (topologically equivalent) to discs.
Meshes with arbitrary topology can be parameterized, provided that the user specifies a cut graph (a set of edges), which defines the border of a topological disc.
So the problem now becomes – how to cut the graph properly (using CGAL’s interface).
I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789563/surface-parametrization) from 3 years ago that went unanswered.

P.S. 
If someone can point me to a different library that can do the job, that’ll be just as great.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you have something that is topologically a sphere you can use [`Surface_mesh_parameterization::Orbifold_Tutte_parameterizer_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html#title17) without having to define cuts.

Comment: thanks Sloriot, but then
"The algorithm requires the user to select a set of vertices of the input mesh and mark them as cones, which will be the singularities of the unfolding."
so how does one go about selecting cones?